# How can I blur an UIImageView's image?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to blur the background image of a UITableView's cell.

I currently have the following code (got it from research):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        var imageView = UIImageView()
        var image = UIImage(data: events[indexPath.row].valueForKey("image") as NSData)
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds
        imageView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        imageView.image = image
        cell.backgroundView = imageView
        return cell
}
```

My background-images are showing up fine, however the blur effect doesn't.
There's no warnings/errors and I really do not know what the issue here is.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIImageView and create blur view like this

```
class BlurImageView: UIImageView {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!){
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)   
      var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
      var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
      effectView.frame = frame
      addSubview(effectView)
  }
}
```

Comment: What would the NSCoder parameter be then when I initialize a new BlurImageView?

Comment: You can create init without any parameter. OR you can define your image of type BlurImageView in your storyboard

Comment: Thanks, I had to add the init(), init(coder...) and init(frame...) to get rid of errors. I changed my imageView to an instance of BlurImageView, but still only the images are showing up.. no blur effect